# Azure function spin-up. Does making a ProxyFunction call also spin-up Azure Functions?

Tags: c#, azure, http, proxy, azure-functions

Azure function spin-up. Does making a ProxyFunction call, also spin-up Azure Functions, that are in the same domain or Azure Function App?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, making a proxy call will spin up the function runtime.  Proxies and HttpTrigger both share a common http front end in the runtime.